# Can't get dictionary value from key in unicode dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

The following code stores a unicode dictionary in the variable `webproperties_list`:

```
webproperties_list = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId='~all').execute()
profile_id = webproperties_list.get(u'defaultProfileId')
print profile_id
```

For some reason the `.get()` on the key of `u'defaultProfileId'` is giving me `None`, even though I know it is in the response.  I also tried the get without the `u` and I still get a `None` response:

```
profile_id = webproperties_list.get('defaultProfileId')
```

Do I need to do something to the dict before I get the value from the key, or am I doing something else wrong entirely?

UPDATE:

Here is the response I get:

```
{u'username': u'removed', u'kind': u'analytics#webproperties', u'items': [{u'profileCount': 1, u'kind': u'analytics#webproperty', u'name': u'removed', u'level': u'STANDARD', u'defaultProfileId': u'removed'.....
```

I need to retrieve the value of `u'defaultProfileId'`

Not really sure how to get a value from a key that is in a dict within a list within a dict...

Comment: Did you try to print the keys, the type of each key, and each key's encoding?

Comment: what does `print(webproperties_list)` show?

Comment: @wwii `<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>` for `for x in webproperties_list.keys():
        print type(x)`

Comment: @MrAlias hmm, so i am jsut realizing the data i need is in a dict that is in a list that is in the whole response dict

Comment: Does each key's encoding match the encoding of *your key*, e.g. are they both "utf-8" or "latin-q"n.a.

Comment: @wwii not really sure what you mean by that, but i am guessing I am getting `None` because I am looking in the wrong place. I am going to edit my post with the response that I get...probably should have done that initially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out how to access it, it sometimes helps to go step by step:

```
>>> d
{u'username': u'removed', u'items': [{u'profileCount': 1, u'defaultProfileId': u'removed', u'kind': u'analytics#webproperty', u'name': u'removed', u'level': u'STANDARD'}], u'kind': u'analytics#webproperties'}
>>> d['items']
[{u'profileCount': 1, u'defaultProfileId': u'removed', u'kind': u'analytics#webproperty', u'name': u'removed', u'level': u'STANDARD'}]
>>> d['items'][0]
{u'profileCount': 1, u'defaultProfileId': u'removed', u'kind': u'analytics#webproperty', u'name': u'removed', u'level': u'STANDARD'}
>>> d['items'][0]['defaultProfileId']
u'removed'
```

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I guess i should have pretty printed it initially.  I was missing some things...